# How to get MongoDB all indexes usage and size

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am trying to get MongoDB indexes usage and size in the same output.

`db.getCollection(collection).stats().indexSizes;` gives sizes

and `db.getCollection(collection).aggregate({ "$indexStats": {} });` gives just usage.

Is there a command to output both?

Answer (score 0):

Both queries can be combined on intellishell, since it uses syntax similar to javascript we can run the following script.

```js
db = db.getSiblingDB("your-db-name");
const collections = db.getCollectionNames();

const result = [];
for (const collection of collections) {
    const sizes = db.getCollection(collection).stats().indexSizes;
    const indexStats = db.getCollection(collection).aggregate({ "$indexStats": {} }).toArray();
    for (const index of indexStats) {
        index.collection = collection;
        index.size = sizes[index.name];
        result.push(index)
    }
}

print (result)
```

notice the conversion to `.toArray()` in order to loop easily over it.